# Javascript Regex Fetch all XML from Logfile

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this Regex String: "`<\?xml[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<Envelope[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/Envelope>`"

This works by this Log file: http://pastebin.com/Rhcde40q

And now i will make the same by this html encodes log file: http://pastebin.com/21cyQWme

I have made this "`&lt;\?xml[^&gt;]*&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;Envelope[^&gt;]*&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/Envelope&gt;`" but there is no result.

How can i fix this. Please suggest a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In both the links you are having same result, right? Except the second one is encoded.

Comment: its not working because of this `[^&gt;]` this means any char that is not & or g or t or ; oyu could try `positive lookahead`

Comment: you don't need `[^&gt;]` if `<xml>` tag is one line, and never change `[^&gt;]*&gt;` to `.*?&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this regex:

```
&lt;\?xml(.*)&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;Envelope([^]*?)&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/Envelope&gt;
```

for this example it returns 4 groups (note & gt; converted to > by Stackoverflow editor, not me!)

```
 &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
 &lt;Envelope xmlns=&quot;http://www.start.de/2001/11/SipMsgFormat&quot;
   xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;http://www.start.de/schemas/SipMsgFormat/SipMsgFormat.xsd&quot;&gt;
   &lt;Header&gt;
     &lt;Sender&gt;
       &lt;TerminalId&gt;215017&lt;/TerminalId&gt;
       &lt;RequestId&gt;9&lt;/RequestId&gt;
       &lt;ExpCode&gt;QW&lt;/ExpCode&gt;
     &lt;/Sender&gt;
     &lt;Service&gt;
       &lt;Name&gt;ADMI&lt;/Name&gt;
       &lt;Version&gt;01&lt;/Version&gt;
     &lt;/Service&gt;
     &lt;Application&gt;
       &lt;Reset&gt;1&lt;/Reset&gt;
       &lt;Context&gt;G&lt;/Context&gt;
       &lt;Key&gt;1&lt;/Key&gt;
       &lt;ContextFunction/&gt;
     &lt;/Application&gt;
 &lt;ServiceProviderApplicationId&gt;0&lt;/ServiceProviderApplicationId&gt;
   &lt;/Header&gt;
   &lt;Body&gt;
     &lt;CUR Version=&quot;01&quot;&gt;
       &lt;Row&gt;6&lt;/Row&gt;
       &lt;Col&gt;3&lt;/Col&gt;
     &lt;/CUR&gt;
     &lt;ADI Version=&quot;01&quot;&gt;
       &lt;MonitorStopCurrent&gt;X&lt;/MonitorStopCurrent&gt;
     &lt;/ADI&gt;
   &lt;/Body&gt;
 &lt;/Envelope&gt;
```

Group #1  Length: 52

```
 version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?
```

Group #2  Length: 1

```
 <nothing>
```

Group #3  Length: 217

```
 xmlns=&quot;http://www.start.de/2001/11/SipMsgFormat&quot;
  xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;http://www.start.de/schemas/SipMsgFormat/SipMsgFormat.xsd&quot;
```

Group #4  Length: 855

```
  &lt;Header&gt;
      &lt;Sender&gt;
        &lt;TerminalId&gt;215017&lt;/TerminalId&gt;
        &lt;RequestId&gt;9&lt;/RequestId&gt;
        &lt;ExpCode&gt;QW&lt;/ExpCode&gt;
      &lt;/Sender&gt;
      &lt;Service&gt;
        &lt;Name&gt;ADMI&lt;/Name&gt;
        &lt;Version&gt;01&lt;/Version&gt;
      &lt;/Service&gt;
      &lt;Application&gt;
        &lt;Reset&gt;1&lt;/Reset&gt;
        &lt;Context&gt;G&lt;/Context&gt;
        &lt;Key&gt;1&lt;/Key&gt;
        &lt;ContextFunction/&gt;
      &lt;/Application&gt;
  &lt;ServiceProviderApplicationId&gt;0&lt;/ServiceProviderApplicationId&gt;
    &lt;/Header&gt;
    &lt;Body&gt;
      &lt;CUR Version=&quot;01&quot;&gt;
        &lt;Row&gt;6&lt;/Row&gt;
        &lt;Col&gt;3&lt;/Col&gt;
      &lt;/CUR&gt;
      &lt;ADI Version=&quot;01&quot;&gt;
        &lt;MonitorStopCurrent&gt;X&lt;/MonitorStopCurrent&gt;
      &lt;/ADI&gt;
    &lt;/Body&gt;
```